# Print Preview stuck on chrome but in firefox it's working

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf, printing

I have a problem with headless chrome print url to pdf it lead me to this issue.

I have a page which is a bit big https://master-7rqtwti-wnjvz3rv66pcy.eu-5.platformsh.site/en/msf_pdf/book/339?no_lang

When I open it in Chrome and press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in Windows) print preview stuck for ever ( I tried it even with incognito mode without any plugin but the same).
[image]

I tried the same in Firefox and it's working well.

[image]

I'm wondering what could be the reason, is there any issue on that page that cause Chrome to crash?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I don´t know how to fix it, but as a workaround I´m using CTRL+SHIFT+P: It opens a popup without print preview.

Comment: ctrl + shift + P, even command +shift +P do nothing in mac.
btw, I'm looking for the reason becase I have the isssue in generation code with headless chrome that I believe the reason is the same  but thanks for the answer.